# ORA-06550:Proc p1 must be declared, while executing the procedure from java app,

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have two schemas s1 and s2, I have created a proc p2 in s2 and in p2, I have a select query from table t1 in s1,
I have provided grant select access from table t1 to s2 and can run the same proc from the SQL developer also, while running from the Java application, I am getting the below error.
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'p2' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

the procedure p2 just select the query and grabs that data and sends back that data as an array type, able to query the same table t1 from schema s2 in SQL developer,
I have provided p2 execute grant access to s2, still not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it,

- procedure `p2` is owned by user (schema) `s2`
- you granted execute on `p2` to user (schema) `s1`
- when `p2` procedure is called from Java application, you get error that `p2` must be declared
- it means that `p2` doesn't exist (or is inaccessible) in schema you're currently logged in
- therefore, which user are you connected to?

  - if it were `s2`, then `p2` would be accessible
  - if it is `s1` (which is what I presume), then

    - although grant exists - procedure isn't "visible" to `s1`
    - what to do?

      - call procedure by specifying its owner. For example not just by `p2`, but `s2.p2`
      - or, create a **synonym** in schema `s1`:

        ```
        create synonym p2 for s2.p2;
        ```

Comment: thanks for the answer,I have changed the java code from p2 to s2.p2 yet, I am getting the same exception like s2.p2 must be declared.

Comment: I don't know Java. But, I presume that you must have established connection to Oracle database. Which user are you connected to? S1, S2 or neither of these two?

Comment: I am connected to S2 from java application, and procedure p2 is in S2 only, still getting p2 must be declared.